# I am having problems with places when selecting cities like Madrid o Barcelona

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, geometry, google-places-api

I am using the places API and the autocomplete functionality and when I try to select cities like Madrid, Barcelona o Rome (I guess there must be more cases) I am not receiving the proper information (I am just receiving the name, but the geometry and the address_components for example are missing).

In addition, I have tried these particular cases in the Place Autocomplete Sample (https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) and the problems are very similar.

Is someone else having these problems?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum working sample? :)

Comment: Obviously a temporary bug that was already reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188872) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encountered this issue as well; this was reported in Google's Issue Tracker here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145144256 and has just been fixed.

If you still experience these issues please add a comment to the bug so that Google Engineers can look into your case.

Hope this helps!